# Padding Around DIVs and Workaround

Tags: html, css

I currently have the below code to run checkboxes for selecting equipment to hire. In the original code I just had the checkboxes, but now I have added information regarding the equipment. I am having issues as

ONE:
I would like to add padding around each item, or make them 50% wide, but center of that 50%. (If that makes sense.)

TWO:
I want to be able to add future equipment without the bottom "NEXT", "PREVIOUS" or "RESET" buttons moving up. (As the equipment information boxes are set to "float: left".

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s5xkts1u/

HTML:

```
          <div class="AccordionPanel" id="acc-step-3">
                <div class="AccordionPanelTab">Step Three - Equipment Package</div>
                <div class="AccordionPanelContent">

                    <div class="form-gap"></div>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">2x Behringer B615D PA Speakers</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            A pair of 1500W Behringer, Powered PA Speakers. With so much power in their sound
                            reproduction, they are sure to distribute the sound to all your audience! Not only
                            is power a major factor in this amazing German engineered beauty, but the quality
                            is second to none!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="speaker" id="speaker" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab speaker" for="speaker"></label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x Behringer B1800HP PA Subwoofer</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            A 2200W Behringer, Powered PA Subwoofer is one way to pack that extra BASS punch at
                            your next event! With so much power in their sound reproduction, they are sure to
                            distribute the sound to all your audience! Not only is power a major factor in this
                            amazing German engineered beauty, but the quality is second to none!
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="subwoofer" id="subwoofer" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab subwoofer" for="subwoofer">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x Smoke Machine</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            SMOKE MACHINE INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="smoke-machine" id="smoke-machine" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab smokemachine" for="smoke-machine">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x Moving Head</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            MOVING HEAD INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="moving-head" id="moving-head" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab acme" for="moving-head">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x 4 Gun Laser System</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            4 GUN LASER SYSTEM INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="four-gun-laser" id="four-gun-laser" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab fourgunlaser" for="four-gun-laser">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x Low Lying Smoke Machine</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            LOW LYING FOG MACHINE INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="low-lying-fog" id="low-lying-fog" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab lowlyingfog" for="low-lying-fog">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">2x 1500W Strobes</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            STROBE INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="strobes" id="strobes" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab strobes" for="strobes">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">1x Red Laser System</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            RED LASER SYSTEM INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="red-laser" id="red-laser" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab redlaser" for="red-laser">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">2x Mirror LED Lighting</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            MIRROR LED INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="mirror-led" id="mirror-led" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab mirrorled" for="mirror-led">
                    </label>

                    <div class="equipment-info">
                        <div class="equipment-info-header">6x Beamz LED Par Cans</div>
                        <div class="equipment-info-text">
                            LED PAR CAN INFORMATION GOES HERE
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipment" value="led-pc" id="led-pc" class="equipment">
                    <label class="equipment-lab ledpc" for="led-pc">
                    </label>

                    <div class="form-gap"></div><br>

                    <input name="previous" id="acc-step-prev-3" type="button" class="form-btn form-prev" value="Previous">
                    <input name="next" id="acc-step-next-3" type="button" class="form-btn form-next" value="Next"><br>
                    <input name="reset" type="reset" class="form-btn form-reset" value="Reset">

                    <div class="form-gap"></div>

                </div>              
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox].equipment {
    display: none;
}
label {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.25s ease-in-out;
}
.equipment-lab {
    width: 20%;
    min-width: 175px;
    max-width: 175px;
    min-height: 175px;
    max-heiht: 175px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
    border-top-left-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}


input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.speaker {
    background: url(../_assets/b615_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.subwoofer {
    background: url(../_assets/b1800hp_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.smokemachine {
    background: url(../_assets/smoke_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.acme {
    background: url(../_assets/acme_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.fourgunlaser {
    background: url(../_assets/4gunlaser_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.lowlyingfog {
    background: url(../_assets/lowlying_150px_na.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.strobes {
    background: url(../_assets/strobes_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.redlaser {
    background: url(../_assets/redlaser_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.mirrorled {
    background: url(../_assets/mirrorled_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label.ledpc {
    background: url(../_assets/ledpc_150px_checked.png);
    opacity: 1;
}

.speaker {
    background: url(../_assets/b615_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.speaker:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.subwoofer {
    background: url(../_assets/b1800hp_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.subwoofer:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}

.smokemachine {
    background: url(../_assets/smoke_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.smokemachine:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.acme {
    background: url(../_assets/acme_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.acme:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.fourgunlaser {
    background: url(../_assets/4gunlaser_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.fourgunlaser:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.lowlyingfog {
    background: url(../_assets/lowlying_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.lowlyingfog:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.strobes {
    background: url(../_assets/strobes_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.strobes:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.redlaser {
    background: url(../_assets/redlaser_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.redlaser:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.mirrorled {
    background: url(../_assets/mirrorled_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.mirrorled:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
.ledpc {
    background: url(../_assets/ledpc_150px.png);
    opacity: 0.5;
    cursor: pointer;
    min-width: 175px;
}
.ledpc:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}



.equipment-info {
    width: 30%;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 0px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    float: left;
    height: 175px;
}
.equipment-info-header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    min-width: 175px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: nav-item;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: 900;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
}
.equipment-info-text {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: nav-item;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

Is there any way to do this? Maybe a TABLE and make each ITEM (image and information) a CELL?

Comment: Your question is not clear enough.

Comment: I want to add a padding around my "equipment-lab" and "equipment-info". (15px)

Then add a padding around the "equipment-info-text" without the text moving into other DIVs (5px)

OR

Change the current code to work maybe more like a "display: table"? (To make things easier for future equipment additions)

Comment: [Check it](https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/s5xkts1u/1/). What about the `equipment-info-text`? The text is too much long, so what you want to do?

Comment: That is pretty damn close to what I am looking for! But when I downsize the boxes, I dont want the image for the information to drop below, I would like BOTH information AND image drop together. Maybe just place the checkbox/label/image in a new DIV? Or would that then mess up what you have accomplished?

Comment: Oh, and I was hoping to add padding around BOTH the image and information area for each section, however keep each SET of IMAGE AND INFORMATION together?

Comment: Can you please give the output image? I mean what you are looking for?

Comment: I will create an image now

Comment: @FrayneKonok: http://www.djscimmia.com/image.png Maybe just a bit more gapping above each item though.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a CSS framework with a grid system, like Bootstrap or Foundation?

Unfortunately, your code is quite convoluted and hard to follow, and excessive use of `float`ing can cause issues.

Comment: Do this thing in the comment section, this is the answer area.

Comment: This is should be a comment

Comment: I have created a jsFiddle to (hopefully) make things a little clearer.

Comment: This is NAA (Not An Answer) and should in a comment. Yes, it's frustrating, you'll have to wait for 50 rep to be able to comment. We've all been through that.

Comment: Please read this http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258610/how-should-one-ask-for-clarification-on-a-question-if-they-cant-yet-comment and delete your answer.